# @Html.RadioButtonFor postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to update other controls on the form as soon as I choose a radio button.

How do I get these controls to call the controller as soon as a radio button is clicked.  A separate submit (actionLink) button isn't suitable.

My code is

```
<label for="ApplicationTypes_Single">On your own?</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ApplicationType, "Single", new { id = "ApplicationTypes_Single" })

<label for="ApplicationTypes_Joint">With someone else?</label>
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.ApplicationType, "Joint", new { id="ApplicationTypes_Joint" })
```

the control dependant on that selection is

```
@if(Model.ApplicationType == AffordabilityPage1.ApplicationTypes.Joint)
{
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecondAge)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecondAge)
}
```

Many thanks for any tips given.

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript in order to achieve this. For example if you are using jquery you could subscribe for the change event of those radio buttons and take some action:

```
$(function() {
    $(':radio[id^="ApplicationTypes"]').change(function() {
        var value = $(this).val(); // will equal Single or Joint
        // Depending on what you are trying to achieve either send an AJAX request
        // or force the submission of some form in order to send the new value to the server
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this and sure enough it works, I still have a lot to learn like how to finish it but this is a great start.  Pretty sure I can find example of how to do that.  Just knowing it's the right path is progress.  Many thanks.